# How to take multiple user inputs using if-else statements in java.

Tags: java, if-statement, menu, statements

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment6 {

public static void commandList()
{

    System.out.println("Command Options------------");
    System.out.println("a: Create a new table");
    System.out.println("b: Change the row sizes");
    System.out.println("c: Change the column sizes");
    System.out.println("d: Change the data types");
    System.out.println("e: Change the formats");
    System.out.println("f: Display the table");
    System.out.println("g: Display the log data");
    System.out.println("?: Display this menu");
    System.out.println("q: Quit the program");
    System.out.println("---------------------------");
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Command Options------------");
    System.out.println("a: Create a new table");
    System.out.println("b: Change the row sizes");
    System.out.println("c: Change the column sizes");
    System.out.println("d: Change the data types");
    System.out.println("e: Change the formats");
    System.out.println("f: Display the table");
    System.out.println("g: Display the log data");
    System.out.println("?: Display this menu");
    System.out.println("q: Quit the program");
    System.out.println("---------------------------");

    String input = "";
    System.out.println("Please input a command:");
    input = in.nextLine();


    do
    {
if (input.equals("a"))
{
    System.out.println("a [Input three integers to ititialze a table:] ");
    int newTable = in.nextInt();
}
    else if (input.equals("b"))
{
    System.out.println("Change the row sizes");
    int newRow = in.nextInt();
}
else if (input.equals("c"))
{
    System.out.println("c [Type an integer to update the table column]: ");
    int newColumn = in.nextInt();
}
else if (input.equals("d"))
{
    System.out.println("d [Type an integer to update the data type]: ");
    int newDataType = in.nextInt();
}
else if (input.equals("e"))
{
    System.out.println("e [Type and integer to update printf format]: ");
    int newPrintf = in.nextInt();
}
else if (input.equals("f"))
{
    System.out.println("f [Display the table]");
}
else if (input.equals("g"))
{
    System.out.println("g [Display the log data]");
}
else if (input.equals("?"))
{
    commandList();
}
else
    {
    System.out.println("Invalid ***Type ? to get commands***");
    }
    }
    while (!input.equals("q"));
{

}

}
    }
```

I created a menu and I am asking the user to input a letter and the program will           show a command option they choose. Right now I have it so if the user inputs "a" then "Input three integers to initialize the table" will print. I need it to then print "Please input a command" next but it just keeps printing "Input three integer to itialize the table" I have been trying different methods for a while now and I have no idea what to do. Any help?

Comment: If you want the user to give you another `input`, put the statement that inputs `input` inside the loop, instead of outside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the bottom of your `do-while` loop:

```
do
{
    if (input.equals("a"))
    {
        System.out.println("a [Input three integers to ititialze a table:] ");
        int newTable = in.nextInt();
    }
    // … more if-else statements

} while (!input.equals("q"));
```

It keeps printing that statement because after the if-else statement finishes, the value of `input` still equals "a" since you haven't changed the value of `input`.

Perhaps you want the user to enter new `input` before the while loop checks again.

```
    // … more if-else statements

    input = in.nextLine(); // <-- add new user input 

} while (!input.equals("q"));
```

And as Juned Ahsan has already said you need to add more code within that first `if` statement to print the other commands that you mentioned.

Comment: Hey thank you Will Newton, that is exactly what I was stuck on. It is working perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop to ask for three integers. Better use array to capture the values. Somethign like this:

```
if (input.equals("a"))
{
    System.out.println("a [Input three integers to ititialze a table:] ");
    int newTable[] = new int[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3 ; i++) {
        System.out.println("Input " + (i+1) + "table value: ");
        newTable[i] = in.nextInt();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since depending on the command entered by the user, the number of inputs you accept from the user changes, try using loops inside the if or else conditions. A do while loop will just keep going the same number of times for any of the commands entered. Try something like this:

```
String input = "";

do {
    System.out.println("Please input a command:");
    input = in.nextLine();

    if (input.equals('a')) {  
        System.out.println("a [Input three integers to ititialze a table:] ");
        int newTable[] = new int[3];
        for (int i = 0; i < 3 ; i++) {
            System.out.println("Input " + (i+1) + "table value: ");
            newTable[i] = in.nextInt();
        }
    }
    else if(input.equals('b')) {
        // Accept as many inputs you want for command 'b'
    }
} while (!input.equals('q'))
```

The outer do while loop will ensure that you can accept as many commands from the user till the user enters 'q'.